# Steady continuity equation and integrating factors

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-forms, fluid-dynamics

We have the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#:%7E:text=The%20continuity%20equation%20says%20that,of%20charge%20density%20is%20negative.)

$$
\partial_t \, P(\mathbf{x},t) = -\nabla \cdot[ \, P(\mathbf{x},t) \, \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x},t) \, ]
$$

where the positive scalar function $P$ is advected by the smooth field $\mathbf{v}$ (everything can be considered continuous and with continuous derivatives).

Imagine that the field $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$ is prescribed and constant in time. How do we get the steady (i.e. time independent) solution  $P(\mathbf{x})$? Namely, we want to solve

$$
\nabla \cdot[ \, P(\mathbf{x}) \, \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) \, ] = 0 \, .
$$

*Note:* this means that  the field $P \mathbf{v}$ is solenoidal and there should be a vector potential $P \mathbf{v} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$.
Therefore, the function $P$ is a sort of "[integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)" but for the existence of the vector potential (instead of the more usual notion of integrating factor for non-exact 1-forms that involves a scalar potential). Maybe the language of differential forms can help understanding the problem (i.e. looking at $q$ as a 0-form and $\mathbf{w}$ as a 1-form.. or a 2-form, since the divergence should be the [external derivative for 2-forms in three-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Divergence)). Partial answers and insights of any kind are well accepted.

Comment: Is $\mathbf w$ nowhere-vanishing? If $\mathbf w$ vanishes — say when $z=0$ — but $\nabla\cdot\mathbf w$ is nonzero, then you are in trouble. Yes, it's natural to frame this in terms of $2$-forms.

Comment: Thank you! let's say $\mathbf{w}$ is non vanishing. If $\mathbf{w}=0$ only in some isolated points, which is the source of trouble?

Comment: Try $\mathbf w = z \mathbf k$, which vanishes on the $xy$-plane. The vector field $\mathbf w = x\mathbf i + y\mathbf j + z\mathbf k$ vanishes only at the origin.

Comment: For nowhere-vanishing vector fields, try $\mathbf w = (e^{f(x,y)},e^{g(x,y)},0)$ with $f_{xy}\ne g_{xy}$. I don't believe you can find $q$ in this case, but I haven't worked out all the details.

Comment: Related question about the steady state of the diffusion-advection in periodic boundary conditions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759470/532409