# Steady state of diffusion-advection on the torus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, transport-equation, steady-state

Let $P$ be a positive scalar function and $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$ is an assigned smooth vector field. The quantity $P(t,\mathbf{x})$ evolves according to a [transport equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) of the kind
$$
\partial_t P(\mathbf{x},t) = -\nabla \cdot [ \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) P(\mathbf{x},t) -  \nabla P(\mathbf{x},t) ] 
$$
The **steady state** solution $P(\mathbf{x})$ is given by
$$
\nabla \cdot [ \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) P(\mathbf{x}) -  \nabla P(\mathbf{x}) ] = 0
$$
If $\mathbf{v}  = -\nabla U $, then the formal solution has the usual [Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_measure) form
$$
P \propto  e^{-U } 
$$
**Question:** assume  that the above equation is defined on the 2D (flat) torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.
How to deal with the case in which $\mathbf{v} = -\nabla U + \mathbf{q}$, where $U$ has the periodicity imposed by  $\mathbb{T}^2$ and $\mathbf{q} =(q_x,q_y)$ is a constant vector field?

More precisely, I'd like to find the class of solutions of
$$
\nabla \cdot [ \mathbf{q}  P(x,y) -  P(x,y) \nabla U(x,y) -   \nabla P(x,y) ] = 0
$$
with the periodic constraints typical of the flat torus $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, i.e.

$P(0,y) = P(1,y)$,  $\quad P(x,0) = P(x,1)$,
$ \qquad U(0,y) = U(1,y)$, $\quad U(x,0) = U(x,1) \, $.

If $\mathbf{q} = 0$, then the solution $P \propto  e^{-U } $ works.
My feeling is that the problem with $\mathbf{q} \neq 0 $ is not trivial because of the topology of  $\mathbb{T}^2$: the constant field $\mathbf{q}$ is clearly periodic (so it can live on the torus) but has no periodic potential (i.e. the potential should be $-q_x x -q_y y$ that is not periodic).

**EDIT:** I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3607173/532409) about divergence-free fields on a torus. In fact, the field $\mathbf{q}  P(x,y) -  P(x,y) \nabla U(x,y) -   \nabla P(x,y)$ is required to be divergence-free.
Also [these notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/toth/spectral%20geometry.pdf) are interesting and deal with the diffusion on the flat torus (pag. 80).

In terms of differential forms the problem should be (correct me, I am not an expert):

$$J = q P -P dU - d P  \qquad \qquad div(J)=0$$

where $J$ is a current 1-form, $q$ is a constant 1-form, $P$ and $U$ are 0-forms. In particular, we should have that $J = R dg$, where $g$ is a 0-form and $R$ is a 90-degrees rotation (i.e. it is the Hodge dual operator in two dimensions, $J = *dg$). Equivalently, by using a somewhat improper 3D terminology, $J =  rot(A)$, where $A=(0,0,g)$. Maybe the language of differential forms helps understanding why it is not so easy to find a solution when the $\mathbf{q}$ term is switched on.

Since this problem is related to systems studied in Physics (transport equations, Fokker-Planck equations), I posted a [related question on physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566778/226902).

Comment: Related question about steady state of the diffusion equation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3723797/532409

Comment: The letter $d$ is a horrid choice for a constant when we're doing calculus. So now turning a "locally exact" solution into a "globally exact" solution is dependent on the topology of the torus. You need to know that the line integrals of the appropriate dual vector field vanish over both circles.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit with some better constant. Sometimes that coefficient is called $d$ because it is the diffusion coefficient. How is this dual vector field defined?

Comment: We need the divergence $1$-form, not the curl $1$-form, so you have to rotate the vector field $\pi/2$ to turn a flux integral into a work integral.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4182338/532409 "Heat Kernel on a compact manifold without boundary". Important remark: the torus is "stochastically complete": stochastic completeness is the property for a stochastic process
to have "infinite life-time" (the total probability of the particle being found in the state space is constantly equal to 1, i.e. particles do not decay). Interesting and related paper: "Langevin diffusions on the torus: estimation and applications" https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00296